# Track DB Changes

Tags: java, sql, oracle, instrumentation

I am doing a installation where mostly DB changes are running.  I mean insert statements, creation of tables, procedures, functions and various other DDL and DML statements get executed.  These scripts are executed through java-jdbc.

How can I track from DB (by running some query) whether the SQ: scripts are executing or have stopped?

I do have logging in place but for some scenarios I wish to know if the script is still running in DB or its processing has stopped.   How can i check that?

Comment: There is no way to do this without instrumenting the scripts.  So can you re-write the scripts, or are you looking for guidance on how to write better scripts in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this tool](https://code.google.com/p/jdbcspy/) to see what's going on in the JDBC driver.

Although it does not provide the query to see if the scripts are executed or not (not exactly what you're trying to achieve), but it will help you to understand what's going on

Comment: This tools seems good.. but i guess i will have to monitor it to see the progress of sql execution..

Comment: Can v$Session provide some information about DB which i can use to figure out that DB is getting updated and is not stuck or hung..